# d3js line chart -- how to extend last step to end of range?

Tags: d3.js, linechart

It's simple, but I can't get rid of the problem.

A line is a link between two points (values) and is drawn from value A to value B. So let's say A has value 10, B has value 20 and C is missing. The line is now drawn from 0 to 10 to 20 and finished. I want to draw the line from 0 to 10 to 20 to 25. Value is ment as the scale of the x-axis (0, 10, 20, 30, 40). Is this possible without changing the beginning of my line, so it still starts at the zero-point of the x-axis?

Without drawing a additional line from 20 to 25 of course :)

The code of my line:

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
        .defined(function (d) { return d.value != null; })
        .x(function (d, i) {                
            return x(d.xValue);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.value);
        }).interpolate("step-after");
```

thx in advance

Here two pictures. The first one, how it looks like now, and the second one, how it should look like.

[image: now]
<sub>(source: [www.axi.at](http://www.axi.at/webimages/year2013_old.png))</sub>

[image: then]
<sub>(source: [www.axi.at](http://www.axi.at/webimages/year2013_new.png))</sub>

©a-x-i (d3js is driving my crazy, but it's cool....)

Comment: Why does your svg.line only have a x and a y? It should be x1, y1, x2 and y2.
If you want to redraw the line to make it longer just select it and give it some new start values and end values.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want. How would you get the line to 25 if 25 isn't in your domain?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want the graph to look like, and what your data points would be?

Comment: @EightBitBoy: It's like the code here: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)

Comment: @AmeliaBR: Pictures added in the original question. Thx....

Answer (score 8):

d3 will never extend a line beyond the final data point.  However, the appearance of the line, and how the data points are connected, depends on the [interpolator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate) setting for `d3.svg.line`.

For a simple example, imagine you only had two points (10,20) and (15,30).

The normal (**"linear"**) interpolator would draw a straight line between them.

The **"step-after"** interpolator starts at the first point (10,20), and draws a horizontal line out to the x-value of the second-point (i.e., to (15,20) ), then draws a vertical line up to (15,30).  The result: the first value is shown as a horizontal line that is held constant until the second value applies.

In contrast, the **"step-before"** interpolator starts at the first point (10,20), and draws a *vertical* line up to the y-value of the second-point (i.e., to (10,30) ), then draws the horizontal line to (15,30).  The result: the first value is shown only as the starting point of the vertical step, with the second value being shown as held constant during the time in between.

Finally, the **"step"** interpolator changes y-values *half-way* between the two x-values.  The result is that both start values and end values are shown as horizontal line lasting for half the distance between them.

Here's a comparison of the different line interpolator options:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/c2mru/1/

I think what would look best for you is if you:

- use the "step" interpolator function
- set the x-values for the line to be the *middle* of your horizontal bars.

You do this by changing

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
        .defined(function (d) { return d.value != null; })
        .x(function (d, i) {                
            return x(d.xValue);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.value);
        }).interpolate("step-after");
```

to

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
        .defined(function (d) { return d.value != null; })
        .x(function (d, i) {                
            return x(d.xValue) + x.rangeBand()/2;
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.value);
        }).interpolate("step");
```

This will result in a line that starts at the mid-point of your first bar and ends at the mid-point of your last bar, but clearly shows the value at each bar with a horizontal line.

If your really *must* have the line start and end at the very end of your range, then you have two options:

- Create a [custom interpolation function](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3310323); or,
- Add an "end-value" data point when you pass your data array to `d3.svg.line`.

Comment: P.S.  For anyone stumbling upon this in the future while looking for information on d3 interpolation functions, [this version of the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/c2mru/3/) may be more useful for comparing the different curve interpolators.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a custom interpolation that does a step after to the end of the range?

Comment: @Cameron You could, although the line interpolator doesn't by default receive information about the total range, so you'd need to use a generator pattern: create a function that takes this info & returns the function that will be used by the line generator. Probably easier to pad your data array with that extra end point.