# Does d3.js offer a method to extend my dataset to the origin of my graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Take this scenario from a graph I'm working on at the moment:

[image]

The problem I'm having is in the bottom left. My dataset's first coordinate is defined at approximately (60,5), yet the domain I'm looking to cover extends right down to 0. **Is there any way I can get d3 to extrapolate this data to my origin?** I've browsed the API but nothing clearly stands out.

I'm well aware I could just `.push` a new object with coordinates `(0,0)` onto my dataset array, but I would prefer not to as I may need to do manipulation with my data later, making this an undesirable option.

Comment: Did you try to define the domain in your x axis to be the extent of your data points (ie, min and max values)? This would move automatically your first point as desired.

Comment: I want my dataset to clamp to the origin, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185198/d3js-line-chart-how-to-extend-last-step-to-end-of-range).

> d3 will never extend a line beyond the final data point.

The solution is the following:

> If your really *must* have the line start and end at the very end of your range, then you have two options:
>
> - Create a [custom interpolation function](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3310323); or,
> - Add an "end-value" data point when you pass your data array to `d3.svg.line`.

For me, it looks like I'm going to have to include a "start value" datapoint. Disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided a fiddle i chose to put up a small fiddle to explain this:

My Data set is like this:

```
data = [{
    xval: 10,
    yval: 100
}, {
    xval: 40,
    yval: 90
}, {
    xval: 50,
    yval: 12
}, {
    xval: 90,
    yval: 70
}]
```

You can see the values of x and y value varies from 0 to 100.

So you will define the range like:

```
x.domain([0, 100]);//this will show x axis start from 0
y.domain([0,100]);//this will show y axis start from 0
```

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h3yj9jrh/1/):

as per your requirement you want the y axis to start from 10 so you do

```
x.domain([0, 100]);//this will show x axis start from 0
y.domain([10,100]);//this will show y axis start from 10
```

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h3yj9jrh/)

Hope this solves your problem. ..:)

Comment: Hey, I think I've written my question really badly. Your jsFiddle's still show the problem I'm having. I want my line to extend all the way to 0, even if my data doesn't.

Comment: yep in the dataset i have xval have values above 10 so in order to start from 0 i am doing  _y.domain([0,100]);//this will show y axis start from 0_
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h3yj9jrh/1/

Comment: I want my axis to start at 0, and I want my data to extend to 0, even if the first point doesn't. The js fiddle is incorrect as it shows the data ending at 10. I want to **extrapolate** my dataset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust your data domain to the maximum and the minimum using the  [extent function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) that d3 provides.

```
var x_domain = d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.xval});
var y_domain = d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.yval});
x.domain(x_domain);
y.domain(y_domain);
```

That way the graph will always be adjusted to the data domain in both coordinates whatever data comes.

[Watch this working.](http://jsfiddle.net/h3yj9jrh/2/)